# C programming-In the below program what does '\' means in t[5\]

Tags: c, arrays, slash

Consider:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i,t[5\];
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        t[i\] = 2 * i;
    i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        i += t[i\];
    printf("%d",i);
    return 0;
}
```

What does `\` in array mean?

I found this program in [CLA (C Programming Language Certified Associate) sample paper](http://cppinstitute.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/CLA_sample_exam_questions.pdf).

Comment: Doesn't look like C to me.

Comment: Have you tried to compile it? Did you get errors? You should because the only meaning of the backslash there is a syntax error. Where did you get the code from? Is it perhaps a copy-paste error? Or some failed code-to-html generation?

Comment: And as you can see, markdown codes in code-snippets doesn't work, so please avoid them in code. Use comments in the code instead. Please edit your question to remove the non-working **bold** markup.

Comment: Edited program.

Comment: At best, you have a typesetting or transcoding error.  Evidently, then, it is not safe to use the document from which this program was drawn as a reference for valid C code, and if it were me, I'd treat all similar documents from the same source with suspicion.

Comment: It is question 4 of http://cppinstitute.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/CLA_sample_exam_questions.pdf  In fact it the \\] is in quite a few questions.

Comment: [link]https://cppinstitute.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/CLA_sample_exam_questions.pdf).See question no.4. @JohnBollinger

Comment: Perhaps it is a poorly composed reprint and the \ should be the last character on the line to show the code continues on next line.

Comment: IMO these backslashes are the result of a failed copy/paste operation. Remove them and your program will be fine.

Comment: As I and others have said, @Tapan, the code you are asking about is not valid C.  In particular, the correct answer to question 4 in the document you linked, as it is presented there, is "the compiler rejects the program", or something equivalent.  That is not one of the options provided, so again, I would view that document and others from the same source with suspicion.

Comment: @cup: looks like it's everywhere there's a `]`; definitely some kind of typsetting or transcription error.  Wow, how did that get out the door in such bad shape?

Comment: It usually means someone slightly missed the "enter" key.

Comment: I have contacted cppinstitute about this - they will be correcting it.

Comment: The link in the question is broken (404).

Comment: @cup: That link is broken (*"Oops, This Page Could Not Be Found!"* 404).

Comment: @PeterMortensen - start at https://cppinstitute.org/ and work down from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The program is incorrect, `\]` is a syntax error.

A possible explanation is the author had to escape some of the C operators (such as `[`) to typeset code fragments and he also escaped `]` which the word processing software seems to leave alone...

Ignore these `\` or replace all occurrences of `\]` with `]`.

Note that this is a tricky question, and the programmer who wrote this code should be fired.

Note also that [the document in question](http://cppinstitute.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/CLA_sample_exam_questions.pdf) has other errors. For example Question 11 reads:

> What happens if you try to compile and run this program?
>
> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
>   int main(void) {
>       int t[2\][3\] = { { 3, 2, 1 }, { 1, 2, 3} };
>       printf("%d", sizeof(t) / sizeof(t[1\][1\]));
>       return 0;
>   }
> ```
>
> A. the program outputs 6
>   B. the program outputs 3
>   C. the program outputs 2
>   D. the program outputs 4

Ignoring the `\]`, the program has potential undefined behavior as `%d` expects an `int` but the value passed to `printf()` has type `size_t`.

Questions 13, 14, 15, 17 have a similar problem.

Answer (score 3):

It means:

Christopher Boguslawski, President at the C++ Institute,

had failed to have someone properly check over their sample questions for mistakes.

**The code will not run the ways it's written.**

One could conjecture that they wanted the \ to be at the end of the line (since it's a valid line continuation character) and forgot to put the line feed carriage return in.  While that would fix the problem, it doesn't make sense why they'd do that just before every end bracket.

What makes more sense is they probably did a "find and replace" across their whole document and propagated an error by accident.

In speculation: possibly some typesetter wrote all arrays as: `t<|5|>` (Or some other configuration that made them go back and replace with proper brackets.)

And then in a fit of laziness they did a Find `<|` Replace `[`  Which is ok.

And then Find `|>` Replace `\]` Which is not ok.

Which kind of makes sense since the `\` and `]` are right next to each other on the keyboard.  (They probably fat fingered it.)

The fact that the whole document has a `\` just before every `]` is a smoking gun.

So it's most likely a sloppy Find/Replace that deprecated their whole document.

So it means the `\` in `t[5\]` is an error.

Answer (score 1):

The backslash is not allowed in that case, it's invalid syntax.
You can validate it here at [ideone online](https://ideone.com/06KKkm).
You get the following errors:

```
prog.c: In function ‘main’:
prog.c:4:13: error: stray ‘\’ in program
    int i,t[5\];
             ^
prog.c:7:10: error: stray ‘\’ in program
       t[i\] = 2 * i; i = 0;
          ^
prog.c:11:15: error: stray ‘\’ in program
       i += t[i\];
               ^
```

If you want to compile the code without errors you just have to remove the invalid `\`.

Actually you use the backslash as escape character to use it for example in escape sequences like a new line character `'\n'` which is  described [here at wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C).

Comment: Having put a newline after each \ my version gave answer C: 13.